# writing to a file from Activity and service

Tags: android, android-service

I have my main activity and I have a service (which runs even in the background when the app is closed). I would like to be writing to the same file from the activity AND from the service. what would be the right way to achieve this (design wise)?

One solution is to have a global variable to tell me if the service is currently writing  or if the Activity is doing it ( so I dont end up openning the file twice). Another way is bind the service to the activity and the activity can only write to file by calling a method on the service

Any idea is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: It seems that binding to the service is a more principled approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you don't write the file directly from your `Activity` because this might cause concurrency conflicts with your `Service`. It would be better if you request your `Service` from the `Activity` to write some thing to that file.

> `Activity`<------>`Service`<------->`File`

Make a method inside the `Service` and call it in your `Activity` with required/desired parameters by this you can avoid the conflicts as only the `Service` will be writing to the `File`.

Comment: Thank you How can I call a method on the service? I guess I need to bind the service to the activity so I can call its method right? StartService does not give me a reference to the service ( I assume)

Answer (score 0):

It is better way to write file in service, Your flow will be like below If I have understand your problem I guess
Start application 
Activity -> Provide info regarding writing file to service -> Start service -> Write file -> Send brodcast to your application

Write a broadcast receiver 
 -> It receive your broadcast when writing file is completed.

Comment: The problem is that my service is not created for the only purpose  of writing to a file. The service is running already, and it will have to write its status to the file regularly. IN ADDITION, Activity has to write to the same file its status on regular interval